# Replace legacyExchangeDN value in ADSI via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, replace, active-directory

I'm looking to correct a small issue in AD where the field I mentioned has a space in the value.

For example:

```
legacyExchangeDN : /o=  First Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=6131a3a42ca946b98cc146345cfd0c2e-Ron E
```

Should look like this:

```
legacyExchangeDN : /o=First Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=6131a3a42ca946b98cc146345cfd0c2e-Ron E
```

This is affecting multiple users and I can manually update the value in the AD Attribute Editor, but I was hoping to be able to automate this.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#List all users to check existing values

$ADUserList = Get-ADUser -Filter* -Properties * | fl name, EmailAddress, legacyExchangeDN
     
#Replace value with space with value without space

Set-ADUser reyer -Replace @{legacyExchangeDN="/o=  ","/o="}
```

The second line produces the following error:

```
Set-ADUser : Multiple values were specified for an attribute that can have only one value
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ADUser reyer -Replace @{legacyExchangeDN="/o=  ","/o="}
```

It feels like I'm missing something easy here, but I cannot find it.  I am testing this with one user. I would like to replace the value against all remaining users in one script once tested.  If I could target just the users that match the criteria of having a space in the field that would surely be helpful for either storing it or piping that over.

My final result would look like:

1. Target users with a space(s) present in the text value of the legacyExchangeDN → `/o=`
2. Replace just the `/o=`   with `/o=` while preserving the remainder of the text value → `/o=First Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=6131a3a42ca946b98cc146345cfd0c2e-Ron E`

Comment: Swap the fl for Select and see if it doesn't work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter { legacyExchangeDN -like '*/o= *' } -Properties @('name','EmailAddress','legacyExchangeDN')
ForEach ($User in $Users)
{
    $Replace = $User.legacyExchangeDN -replace '/o=\s','/o='
    Set-ADUser -Identity $User -Replace @{ legacyExchangeDN = $Replace }

    Write-Host ('Updated "{0}" ({1}) to "{2}"' -f
        @($User.name,$User.EmailAddress,$Replace))
}
```

This will be faster as well.  The mantra is: Filter Left, Format Right.  [`Set-ADUser` takes an `ADUser` object](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh852287.aspx).  `-Replace` takes a `[HashTable]` where you're assigning a new value to the named property (as it appears in LDAP).

(update: removed pipeline for foreach)

---

To implement logging, replace `Write-Host` with:

```
'Updated "{0}" ({1}) to "{2}"' -f @($User.name,$User.EmailAddress,$Replace) |
    Out-File -FilePath "$env:UserProfile\ADChanges.txt" -Append
```

Comment: @CharlieEcho Turns out `-Filter` doesn't support `-match`.  I've updated to a supported operation.

Comment: @CharlieEcho Fixed another thing I forgot to edit.  My solution as-is should be working with the latest edit.

Comment: Your current code worked, even though it did spit an arguement error at me for the output portion.

*Write-Host : Missing an argument for parameter 'ForegroundColor'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.ConsoleColor' and try again.
At line:7 char:47
+     Write-Host 'Updated "{0}" ({1}) to "{2}"' -f
+                                               ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Host], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand*

Comment: @CharlieEcho Ah, I forgot to put a parenthesis around the argument. Updated.

Comment: @CharlieEcho If you think there are multiple spaces, change the first `-replace` argument to: `'/o=\s+'`.  This will cause it to capture one plus however many spaces it finds to replace.